# Create function to convert given string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Create function to convert given string to the output below

```
// Input
const optionRule = '{1069} AND ({1070} OR {1071} OR {1072}) AND {1244} AND ({1245} OR {1339})';

// Output Example
/* const output = {
  and: [
    1069,
    { or: [1070, 1071, 1072] },
    1244,
    { or: [1245, 1339] },
  ]
}; */

let result = 'result'

console.log('result:', result);
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't just ask help for the solution. Try to solve it yourself and put some code in the question.
Since, this community is for helping. I will give you a simple solution.

```
const fnconvertString = (str) => {
    const strArr = str.split(' AND ')
    const output = strArr.map(item => {
    let temp = item.split(' OR ')
    if (temp.length < 2) {
            return Number(temp[0].replace(/[{()}]/g, ''))
    } else {
        let temp1 = temp.map(i => Number(i.replace(/[{()}]/g, '')))
      return {
        'or': temp1
      }
    }
  })
  return output
}
console.log( fnconvertString(optionRule))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const output = arr => {
let result = {}
let newArr = []
let strArr = arr.split(' AND ')
strArr.forEach(str => {
    if (str.includes('OR')) {
        newArr.push({
            or: str.match(/\d+/g).map(val => +val),
        })
    } else {
          newArr.push(Number(str.match(/\d+/g)))
    }
})
    result.and = newArr
    return result
}
console.log(output(optionRule))
```